# Time calculation in the main game loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio

There is the code in the Quake 2 main game loop implementation:

```
if (!initialized)
{   // let base retain 16 bits of effectively random data
    base = timeGetTime() & 0xffff0000;
    initialized = true;
}
curtime = timeGetTime() - base;
```

I'm wondering about the line `base = timeGetTime() & 0xffff0000`. Why are they applying the `0xffff0000` mask on the retrieved time? Why not to use just:

```
if (!initialized)
{   // let base retain 16 bits of effectively random data
    initialTime = timeGetTime();
    initialized = true;
}
curtime = timeGetTime() - initialTime;
```

???
What is the role of that mask?

Comment: One possible benefit of the mask is that the result of the function will not always be 0 when first called. The "epoche" of the clock has large discrete steps. The function could, for example, be used to seed a PRNG in the way `srand(time(NULL))` is used (though it would probably do an even worse job).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Am i right that the function returns 0 ONLNY when the time captured would be just the form of: xxxx0000 hex and the code wolud run as fast that < 1 ms?

Comment: Assuming this function returns `curTime` and assuming `timeGetTime()` is in milliseconds it would return 0 only when a) the first call to `timeGetTime()` had all the lower order bits as 0 and b) less than 1 millisecond has passed since the initial time was measured. The function may return 0 again in the distant future when the clock representation wraps around. Edit : If `timeGetTime()` returns a 32 bit value, this may occur a little less than once an hour.

Comment: @ Ok, Thx for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if (!initialized)` check will only pass once. Therefore `curtime` will become larger with each gameloop, which wouldn't be the case with suggested rewrite, since the upper word may increase after sufficiently many gameloops.

Likely this is in preparation of an int-to-float conversion where smaller numbers result in higher accuracy. (Such as adjusting for the time between two frames and numerically integrating game states over time; but also rendering smooth animations)

Comment: Ok, but why arew they masking  the starting, initial time with 0x0000ffff? Isn't it sufficient ti just take a initial time once and then squentionally only subract current time from the initial like so: `curtime = timeGetTime() - initialTime`?;

Comment: @Can You be so nice and explain, on example Your's answers second paragraph ("Such as adjusting for the time between two frames and numerically integrating game states over time; but also rendering smooth animations")?

Answer (score 0):

The way it is implemented, `base`, and hence `curtime`, will assume different values depending on `initialized` being `true` or `false`.

Comment: Ok, but what the masking is for?

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft Docs, the description of timeGetTime() is:

> The timeGetTime function retrieves the system time, in milliseconds.
> The system time is the time elapsed since Windows was started.
>
> Remarks
>
> The only difference between this function and the timeGetSystemTime
> function is that timeGetSystemTime uses the MMTIME structure to return
> the system time. The timeGetTime function has less overhead than
> timeGetSystemTime.
>
> Note that the value returned by the timeGetTime function is a DWORD
> value. The return value wraps around to 0 every 2^32 milliseconds,
> which is about 49.71 days. This can cause problems in code that
> directly uses the timeGetTime return value in computations,
> particularly where the value is used to control code execution. **You
> should always use the difference between two timeGetTime return values
> in computations.**
>
> The default precision of the timeGetTime function can be five
> milliseconds or more, depending on the machine. You can use the
> timeBeginPeriod and timeEndPeriod functions to increase the precision
> of timeGetTime. If you do so, the minimum difference between
> successive values returned by timeGetTime can be as large as the
> minimum period value set using timeBeginPeriod and timeEndPeriod. Use
> the QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency functions to
> measure short time intervals at a high resolution.

In my opinion, this will help improve the accuracy of time calculations.