# Calculationg time in game msg loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm playing with the original Quake2 game source code for Windows. There is the code which me some doubts an questions.

Sys_Milliseconds function implementation (*q_shwin.c*):

```
/*
================
Sys_Milliseconds
================
*/
int curtime;
int Sys_Milliseconds (void)
{
    static int      base;
    static qboolean initialized = false;

    if (!initialized)
    {   // let base retain 16 bits of effectively random data
        base = timeGetTime() & 0xffff0000;
        initialized = true;
    }
    curtime = timeGetTime() - base;

    return curtime;
}
```

Sys_Milliseconds function usage (*sys_win.c*) - the main game loop:

```
...
    oldtime = Sys_Milliseconds ();

        /* main window message loop */
    while (1)
    {
        // if at a full screen console, don't update unless needed
        if (Minimized || (dedicated && dedicated->value) )
        {
            Sleep (1);
        }

        while (PeekMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE))
        {
            if (!GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
                Com_Quit ();
            sys_msg_time = msg.time;
            TranslateMessage (&msg);
            DispatchMessage (&msg);
        }

        do
        {
            newtime = Sys_Milliseconds ();
            time = newtime - oldtime;
        } while (time < 1);
//          Con_Printf ("time:%5.2f - %5.2f = %5.2f\n", newtime, oldtime, time);

        //  _controlfp( ~( _EM_ZERODIVIDE /*| _EM_INVALID*/ ), _MCW_EM );
        _controlfp( _PC_24, _MCW_PC );
        Qcommon_Frame (time);

        oldtime = newtime;
    }
...
```

Now I'm wondering is it at all possible for the `time` variable to be < 1? since the `oldtime` will ALWAYS be < then `newtime` just because we take the `newtime` AFTER the `oldtime`!?

Can You be so nice and try to explain it to Me.
Thx.

Comment: unless one millisecond passed the difference is `0` , no?

Comment: I assume to avoid problems with division by 0 (a lot of animation and physics calculations divide by delta time) the loop wants to wait until at least 1 unit of time (whatever that unit is) has passed.

Comment: Don’t do that. The main reason Quake 2 did, it supported Windows 95. Windows NT (including modern Windows 10) has QueryPerformanceCounter API. Slightly slower because a kernel call, but totally fine to call 60-240 times per second. Will get you much higher resolution of the time, the precision is usually less than a microsecond.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux. Yeah, i know it but i'm still wondering is it's possible for the `time` variable to be < 1!? What could be the case it' will be be < 1!?

Comment: @idclev463035818 @FrançoisAndrieux. Yeah, i know it but i'm still wondering is it's possible for the `time` variable to be < 1!? What could be the case it' will be be < 1!?

Comment: what do you expect it to be when less than one millisecond has passed?

Comment: @Derek81 Look at your wall clock, blink and then look at it again. It is likely that it will indicate the same number of seconds. If you compare the two, it looks like 0 time has passed between the two observations. This happens when you observe a clock twice within 1 unit of its resolution. If you finish a loop iteration in less than 1 millisecond, the next iteration may read the same millisecond and appear as if 0 time has passed. Your delta time is an integer. It will never record fractions of a second.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I'm talking about the `do {...} while (time < 1)` fragment. Since the `newtime` is always > then the `oldtime` then this loop has no sense to exist!

Comment: @Derek81 *"Since the newtime is always > then the oldtime"* This is an incorrect assumption. `newtime` can be equal to `oldtime`.

Comment: the loop exits as soon as `time >= 1`. If the the values are in milliseconds then their difference is 0 until one millisecond has passed.

Comment: its just repeating what I already wrote in the first comment... another try: Suppose 1 microsecond has passed then the difference in milliseconds is 0.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, Yeah, OK friend You're right. But what is the masking with `0xffff0000` for?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yeah, OK friend You're right. But what is the masking with `0xffff0000` for?

Comment: you already asked that question (about the mask) and you got answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63564634/time-calculation-in-the-main-game-loop

Comment: @idclev463035818, Yes, right but i actually don't  get that answers. Can You try to explain it for me in Yours words please?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, "If the result of Sys_Milliseconds is used to seed a PRNG it may be desirable for the initial value of Sys_Milliseconds to drift with the real time to a small extent" - could You please explain me what do you mean with it?

Comment: @Derek81 I posted a comment in the other question. It is more appropriate there.